# Robocopy Maxage Minage with Mir Parameter

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-4.0, robocopy

I am using Robocopy from Source to Destination.

The following will move all the files.

```
Step 1: robocopy c:\Source C:\Destination /MIR
```

Now when I execute second command in step, anything before January 1, 2019 should be removed from destination with /MIR parameter, however this is not occuring (files after Jan 2019, still remain in folder instead of being deleted with /MIR command). How would I resolve this issue? Remove anything before 20190101?

```
Step 2: robocopy c:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /maxage:19000101 /minage:20190101"
```

Comment: so ... what IS occurring? [*grin*] /////  your options mean "exclude anything older than MAXAGE _and_ exclude anything newer than MINAGE". that seems to mean you otta be mirroring any file that is in the range `1900-01-01...2019-01-01`. do you have any such files? is ANYTHING being mirrored?

Comment: yes, I have files before 2019 and after 2019, however when I run step 2,  files after 2019 should be removed

Comment: i don't think that is not what `/mir` does. step 2 is only targeting files BEFORE 2019 and AFTER 1900 ... and it is NOT moving them, just copying them.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming code questions of the `if/else/endif` variety. This Q is more appropriate on https://superuser.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This does seem odd behavior as one would think that what you are trying to use the `/MINAGE` switch to select everything younger than January 1, 2019. Then combine it with the `/MIR` switch, or more specifically the `/PURGE /E` switch, to remove the extra files and directories that are **after** January 1, 2019.

The reason that this doesn't work is that the `/MINAGE` switch only affects the files that are *selected to be* **copied**, even when the `/MIR` command works as expected.

Say we have 2 files 1 older than January 1, 2019, and one newer.

```
C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt     
 File-2019.txt
```

When we run the standard `\MIR` command:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR
```

Both files get copied as expected.

```
2 files Copied

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
```

If we add an extra file to the destination:

```
C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
                    File-2020.txt
```

And re-run the `/MIR` command:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR
```

We get, as expected, the extra file is deleted:

```
2 files Skipped
1 files Extras

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
```

To the `\MIR` command, when we then add a `/MINAGE` parameter thinking that we are asking for everything Jan 1 2019 and older to stay and the rest to go:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /MINAGE:20190101
```

We get the unexpected:

```
2 files Skipped

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
```

To better illustrate what is going on, and why it "Skipped" the files, lets add another parameter, Include Skipped `\IS`:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /IS /MINAGE:20190101
```

We get:

```
1 files Copied
1 files Skipped

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
```

That means the `\MINAGE` parameter only *filtered* out what we wanted to ***copy***. If we reset and clear out the directory, and re-run it, we can better see what happened:

```
Remove-Item C:\Destination -Force

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      
 File-2019.txt      

Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /MINAGE:20190101
```

We get:

```
1 files Copied
1 files Skipped

C:\Source         C:\Destination
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt
```

It copied over the **Older** file, and not the **Newer** file. This means that when it iterated through files in the source, it used the `/MINAGE` parameter to figure out only *what* files I need to **copy** over, not what files I need to **Remove**.

The reason for this behavior is because `/MINAGE` and the corresponding `/MAXAGE` parameters is meant for very large directories with slow network links or smaller destination computers, where we typically are only interested in copying over certain sets of files (e.g. only new files from yesterday), and don't necessarily need to copy over *all* the files. Most often in these cases, the mirroring is not usually performed or desired as the set of files are typically "Deltas".

To highlight copy over remove, if mirror the directories and then we add 2 extra files, one older and one newer to the *Destination*:

```
C:\Source         C:\Destination
                    File-2017.txt
 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
                    File-2020.txt
```

And re-run with the Include Skipped `/IS` so that we can see what is being copied:

```
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /IS /MINAGE:20190101
```

We get the somewhat surprising:

```
1 files Copied
1 files Skipped
2 files Extras

C:\Source         C:\Destination

 File-2018.txt      File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt      File-2019.txt
```

This highlights that `/MIR` is meant for... well... *Mirroring*. The other parameters are there only to tell it ***what*** to **Copy**.

We start with Source files involved in the copy:

```
C:\Source
 File-2018.txt
 File-2019.txt
```

We apply the filtering by Include skipped `/IS` and `/MINAGE`:

```
C:\Source
 File-2018.txt    <- 1 files Copied
 File-2019.txt    <- 1 files Skipped
```

Then the `\MIR` Mirror command executes and **removes all the files from the Destination that were** ***not included in the Source Files***:

```
C:\Destination
 File-2017.txt    <- 2 files Extra
 File-2020.txt
```

**Regardless of the age of the Extra files**

The easy solution is to just not copy over everything to begin with. Start off with an empty directory, and only copy the files that are younger than January 1, 2019:

```
Remove-Item C:\Destination -Force
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /E /MINAGE:20190101
```

---

Edit

The improved method (instead of removing the entire directory first), you simply run a cleanup script on the destination to remove items younger than January 1, 2019 from your destination first:

```
#Cleanup younger files
Get-ChildItem C:\Destination -Recurse | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date '2019-01-01')} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Mirror over new files
Robocopy.exe C:\Source C:\Destination /MIR /MINAGE:20190101
```

Comment: Dang!  I was hoping by the time I got to the end of this yellow brick road there would be a workaround or solution for a `/purge /e` and `/minage` combo...  A sound solution in the end but me personally I came here hoping to use this as a "cleanup" method if something has not been delete from a directory and is X days old then I will help them out and delete it for them per policy.  Alas, I'm still on the hunt for a solution.

Comment: @ArvoBowen I have added an additional EDIT to the answer for a more "optimum" solution. I agree, a one line `robocopy` script would be preferred, but breaking it up into a 2 part cleanup, then copy script is basically the only way to use `robocopy` to do this.